# How do i reduce my images width in id tags?

Tags: html, css

Using id tag for slidebar , i cant reduce the width and height or cant make it responsive in html body tag size. 
[Here is the screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whlxD.png)

Comment: You're missing a set of quotations after the title attribute.  And there is an extra set at the end of the id.

Comment: Please put the code as a part of question, not as an link to image on external site.

Answer (score 0):

An id is supposed to be a unique identifier for just a single element on the page. So you need to change:

```
id="fixed-width-flamingo"
```

so they read:

```
class="fixed-width-flamingo"
```

I assume you're using either an internal (in the .html < head >) or external (in a .css file) so you also need to change css:

```
#fixed-width-flamingo
```

changes to:

```
.fixed-width-flamingo
```

Typically external .css files are preferred because then changes to that single .css file affect all pages where you include that .css file in the
< head >

So just to go over the attributes one may care to set. Your html should read something like:

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/foo.jpg" title="bar" class="fixed-width-flamingo" /></a>
```

Then your css should read something like:

```
.fixed-width-flamingo {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

I suggest using max-width and max-height instead of just width and height, because then your images can shrink as required, for example on a phone or a tablet.

Also you have a typo which I believe is why you're getting that highlight in your text editor, you need to add a " after ut ac lacus in your last img tag and remove one of the " after fixed-width-flamingo on that line too.